# passar múltiplas variáveis pelo url GET

Tags: php, get

Eu quero fazer passar duas variáveis para outra pagina através do GET. Eu já tenho um a funcionar assim:

```
 <a class='fa fa-remove' href='remover.php?remover=carrinho&id=$idproduto' style='font-size:24px'></a>
```

Mas no que eu estou a fazer agora é um form então o url seria a action do form, e sendo assim não está a funcionar porque envia as variaveis do form e não as que eu escrevi no action, por exemplo:

```
 <form action='quant.php?qtd=carrinho&id=$idproduto'>
 <div class='input-group mb-2' style='text-align: 
      center'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input class='form-control' id='qtd1' name='qtd2'type='text' 
      value='$quantidade'/>
  <div class='input-group-append'>
<div class='input-group-append'>
<button class='btn btn-outline-secondary fa fa-refresh' type='submit'><span 
     class='glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'></span> 
 </button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  </div>
 </div>    
   </div>     
   </form>
```

deveria ir para `quant.php?qtd=carrinho&id=$idproduto` mas vai para `quant.php?qtd2=12`

Eu quero que ele passe o $idproduto e o valor que o utilizador inseriu no inputbox.

Comment: O formulário envia as informações dentro dele. O action é a referência para quem vai processar os dados, tu teria que criar uns input hidden para enviar essas informações juntas.

Answer (score 2):

> Essa combinação de passar valores por url e formulario ao mesmo tempo não acho que dê certo.

A unica forma que conheço é colocar os valores das variáveis dentro de inputs `hidden` para passar via get

```
<form action='quant.php' method="get">
    <div class='input-group mb-2' style='text-align: center'>
    <input name='qtd' type='hidden' value='carrinho'/>
    <input name='id' type='hidden' value='<?php echo $idproduto ?>'/>
        <input class='form-control' id='qtd1' name='qtd2'type='text' value='<?php echo $quantidade ?>'/>
            <div class='input-group-append'>
                <div class='input-group-append'>
                    <button class='btn btn-outline-secondary fa fa-refresh' type='submit'>
                    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'></span> 
                    </button>
                </div>
           </div>    
   </div>     
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
$qtd = $_GET['qtd'];

$id = $_GET['id'];

$qtd2 = $_GET['qtd2'];
```

**Ou**

```
foreach ( $_GET as $chave => $valor ) {
  // $$chave cria as variáveis com os names dos elementos do formulário
  $$chave = trim( strip_tags( $valor ) );
}

echo $qtd;

echo $id;

echo $qtd2;
```